# Spring Security : LDAP Authentication and Search

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I want to convert a normal Spring LDAP integration to Spring Security application. I have the application context as this.

```
<ldap:context-source
            url="ldap://euro.mo.xyz.com:389"
            base="ou=prod,dc=euro,dc=mo,dc=xyz,dc=com"
            username="mydomain\mohan06"
            password="hotStar56" />
```

When I used passwordCompare and userDn, then I got the following exception

```
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09075A, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]
```

After seeing some advice online

I tried using managerDn like the following

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.ldapAuthentication()               
                .userDnPatterns("OU=prod,DC=euro,DC=mo,DC=xyz,DC=com")
                .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
                .userSearchBase("OU=prod,DC=euro,DC=mo,DC=xyz,DC=com")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://ptklt.euro.mo.xyz.com:389")                       
                .managerDn("CN=mydomain\\\\mohan06,OU=prod,DC=euro,DC=mo,DC=xyz,DC=com")
                .managerPassword("hotStar56")
                .root("OU=prod,DC=euro,DC=mo,DC=xyz,DC=com");
```

But now I get the following error, even though my credentials are fine.

```
AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException
```

Should I need to use different credentials for password compare and managerDn?

Comment: If you're getting the exception when it's trying to bind as the manager user, you might want to change the managerDn to not include the root. (I don't know that this is the problem, which is why this is not an answer, but it's the first thing I'd try.) If it successfully binds as the manager user but throws when you try to log in as a normal user, note that userDnPatterns needs to include a "{0}", per Javadoc. Generally this smells like it's using the wrong dns somewhere; hard to telediagnose, but if you fire up a debugger and walk through the auth process, you might find it quickly.

Comment: Removed the root but that did not work.

I also tried using the password compare 

auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid=mydomain\\\\{0},OU=prod,DC=euro,DC=mo,DC=xyz,DC=com")
                .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://ptklt.euro.mo.xyz.com:389")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder());

But this gave error:
: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection.

Comment: I tried using javax.naming.directory without SpringSecurity and that worked. But the same thing on SpringSecurity errs out saying, there should be successful bind.

Comment: How is the managerDn privilege different form userDn privilege? Do I need to apply for manager user separately. Because with Spring Security with a normal User credential, I am not able to bind with Spring Security.